# How to Reduce Time Complexity 

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

Yesterday I have attended for an interview. He gave me few programming questions to solve. When I solved them, the interviewer said it can be done in better Time complexity. I was so much depressed that I cannot do the program in the best time complexity. Finally I am not able to get through the interview process. But what I want to know is how can we do in best time for any problem? What should be my approach to reach that state? I know the perfect answer is **practice**. But still I want to know how and what ways to do a program such that it runs in less time and use best memory. What books I have to read? What problems I have to practice?

**P.S: I know this is not a technical question. But please let me know how can I do that.**

Comment: could u give an example? maybe the reason he didn't hire was some other? difficult to tell.

Comment: You are aware that the best approach to a problem **depends on the problem**, right?  There are no cookie-cutter solutions.  No, not even jQuery.

Comment: @AndersK There are two arrays say B[], A[]. Both of these are of size n. Now I need to calculate B[0 to n-1] such that 
B[0] = A[1] * A[2] * A[3] ... A[n-1]
B[1] = A[0] * A[2] * A[3] ... A[n-1]
ans so on. That is for every B-array of 0 to n index I need to do multiplication of A[] array except the element that has index of B for which we are calculating. I have done this one in O(n^2) he told me it can be done in O(n). Could not figure out how? Simillarly few more questions.

Comment: You must learn to cope better with this sort of interview question.  It's unreasonable to expect someone to know the 'best' algorithm for every problem, so a reasonable interviewer doesn't have such expectations and you shouldn't either. I's reasonable to expect candidates to know the best algorithms (note the plural) for a (small) set of core problems (sorting, searching, domain-specific stuff (number-crunching in my case), ...) and to be able to apply their knowledge of algorithms to novel problems such as those that get thrown at them in an interview.

Comment: @Amarnath, You can assign the value A[0]*A[1]*..*A[n-1] into a variable called `mulA`, then for each i from 0 to n - 1, you can assign B[i] equals to `mulA` `/` `A[i]`. Calculation of `mulA` can be done in `O(n)` and later portion requires another `O(n)` complexity. And `O(n)` + `O(n)` is actually `O(n)`.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark 100% agree with you. There are some problems that could have only one optimal solution and all industries are expecting us to know that. Wired, but that's the truth.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the best books about algorithms, data structures, time and space complexity is [Introduction to Algorithms](http://mitpress.mit.edu/algorithms/). I can also recommend you to read following books for good preparation for an interview:

1. [Cracking the Coding Interview: 150 Programming Questions and Solutions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1466208686)
2. [Programming Interviews Exposed: Secrets to Landing Your Next Job](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/047012167X)
3. [Programming Pearls](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201657880)

Answer (score 3):

Solving this sort of problem involves practice, plus "seeing the trick". For this specific example you might notice that `B[i] = P/A[i]`, where `P` is the product of all the `A[i]` elements multiplied together. So in this case the O(n) performance comes from first calculating `P` once (n-1 multiplications), followed by calculating each `B[i]` (another n divisions).

Sometimes, the best way of 'seeing thew trick' is to look for repeated patterns in the algorithm you use. For your example, note that in your description you actually typed the string `"A[2] * A[3] ... A[n-1]"` twice, so this is the sort of place to think "can I do this thing only once in the algorithm".

Comment: Thanks. I think this is what he was telling me in the interview that there is a pattern look .. look .. look ..:(

Answer (score 1):

Read lots of algorithms and practice them.

Solving problems from online judges is also helpful for increasing efficiency and accuracy of problem solving skill.

List of some judges are given below:

- [UVa Online Judge](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/)
- [Sphere Online Judge (SPOJ)](http://www.spoj.pl/)
- [TopCoder](http://www.topcoder.com/tc)